# wierd way to get chrome, IE 8 and firefox to submit the same form

Tags: javascript, forms, browser, submit, compatibility

This is the only way I found to get all three browsers to submit the form without problems. Is there an obvious reason why this is so? A more elegant solution to this? I'm using jQuery 1.9. Chrome is the odd man out here, as the code in the else is sufficient to submit via IE and Firefox.

```
function submitFormByPost(actionName){ 
     $("#eventAction").val(actionName);

     var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
     if(is_chrome){
          document.getElementById('myForm').method='POST';
          document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
     }
     else{
          document.forms[0].method='POST';
          document.forms[0].submit(); 
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that works in Chrome will work in the others also, so just use that:

```
function submitFormByPost(actionName){ 
  $("#eventAction").val(actionName);
  var frm = document.getElementById('myForm');
  frm.method = 'POST';
  frm.submit();
}
```

Or using jQuery all the way:

```
function submitFormByPost(actionName){ 
  $("#eventAction").val(actionName);
  $('#myForm').attr('method', 'POST').submit();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery should already provide a cross-browser way to submit a form. Try:

```
var $form = $("#myForm");
$form.attr('method', 'post');
$form.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for some older Chrome versions compability. Normally `document.forms[0]` works as well on Chrome as on other browsers. Easiest way to check, open Chrome console and write `console.log(document.forms[0]);` - works fine.